# How do I format the Xbox 360's 4GB internal hard drive?

Tags: xbox-360

When I format my internal HDD on my xbox360 it runs and shows everything deleted. After reboot all the files are back.  What is going on? There are a bunch of corrupted files on the HDD. Is that the issue? If so, how can I get rid of them?

Comment: What tells you the files are corrupt?

Comment: When scanning the files on the xbox it shows a few "corrupted file"  with a yellow exclamation point beside it in the files list.

Comment: Can you delete the corrupted files individually and then reformat?  I don't know if that would help, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: I have tried deleting all the files (corrupted or not) manually.  They appear to be deleted but after the machine is rebooted all the files are back where they were.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following steps:

1. Turn off the console and remove the Xbox 360 hard drive.
2. Turn on the console and turn it off again.
3. Reconnect the hard drive and turn on the console.
4. Change the file system type to 'exFAT' and select 'OK', then select 'Continue' on the next screen.
5. Go to 'My Xbox / System / Memory.' Select 'USB Storage Device / Configure Now' and then accept.
6. Try to format the Storage Device

Comment: I will check tonight but I believe the 4GB models hard drive is internal\onboard.  Is there still a way to disconnect that?

Answer (score 0):

An incorrectly installed hard drive can cause this issue. You can verify correct installation at Add or remove an Xbox 360 Hard Drive.
Turn your Xbox 360 console off and then on again:
Turn off your console, and then remove the Xbox 360 Hard Drive.
Turn your console on and then off again.
Reattach the hard drive, and then turn your console on again.
If you have another hard drive, try it with your console.
Format your hard drive.